# Lollipop unpin screen

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

To unpin a screen on my Nexus 4, it asks me to touch and hold the 'Overview' key, but on my wife's one, it asks me to touch and hold both the 'Back' and the 'Overview' buttons.

Can someone point me out how can I change the screen unpin key combination?

Edit: both phones are running Android version 5.1, build number LMY47O.